# Touchpad Not Working Properly

Tags: touchpad

my laptop's touch pad isn't working smoothly on ubuntu, I have windows 7 on which it works fine but on ubuntu, when I move my finger on the touch pad, the cursor slightly moves ... need help !!!

```
Laptop Model: Haier 7G-5H
OS: Windows 7 And Ubuntu

Laptop Description:
Complete Specifications of Haier 7G - 5H :

[Basic Parameters ]
Category Notebook
Time to market in December 2013
Product Type Home
The thin portable product positioning , Ultrabook notebook
Operating system pre-installed Windows 8

[ Processor ]
CPU series Intel Core i3 4 -generation family
CPU Type Intel Core i3 4005 U
CPU clocked at 1700.000(1.7GHz)
Core frequency 2000.000
3MB cache
Motherboard chipset Intel QM87

[Storage Device ]
Memory capacity 4GB (4GB RAM)
Memory type DDR3 1333MHz
Hard disk capacity 500GB
Hard to describe 5400
No built-in CD-ROM drive type

[ Display ]
Screen size 14.000
Screen resolution 1366x768

[ Graphics ]
Two graphics card type ( performance -level graphics card + integrated graphics )
Graphics chip NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M + Intel GMA HD 4400
Memory Type DDR3
Memory capacity 2GB
128bit memory interface

[ Audio ]
Built-in audio chip audio system
Speaker Built-in speaker

[ Camera / network communications ]
Camera 720p HD webcam
Wireless LAN 802.11b/g/n wireless protocol

[ Interface ]
3 × USB2.0 data interface
Video Interface VGA, HDMI
Reader -in-1 card reader
Audio interface headphone output interface

[ Input Device ]
Touchpad pointing device
Chocolate Keyboard Keyboard description

[ Power Description ]
Battery Type 4-cell lithium battery 

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜↳ ALPS PS/2 Device                         id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
 ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Power Button                             id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Video Bus                                id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Power Button                             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Sleep Button                             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ USB HD Webcam                            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version. Please add output of `xinput` to your question.

Comment: sorry for late reply ... 
1. Ubuntu Version: 14.04 LTS

Comment: 2. Xinput
2. Xinput
Virtual core pointer                          id=2      [master pointer  (3)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer        id=4      [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint          id=12    [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ ALPS PS/2 Device                           id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard                        id=3       [master keyboard (2)]↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                         id=5      [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                                  id=6      [slave  keyboard (3)]

Comment: continue..

    ↳ Video Bus                                id=7 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=8 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                             id=9 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB HD Webcam                            id=10 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]

Comment: Can you read? You can [edit] YOUR QUESTION and add information there.

Comment: any one ?? need help !!!

Comment: Please add output of `uname -a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 by running in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Test the touchpad after reboot.